# Foreach Counter as Array - PHP

Tags: php, foreach, counter, break

I have 20 items in my foreach statement.
I have been added counter using $index = 0; $index++

```
$index = 0;
foreach( $partialStructure as $map ) {

 // i am getting specific number of $tmp for specific subject ( member )
 $tmp = $this->getFieldValueString($field, $value, $subject, $map, $partialStructure);

 $array = array(
      $index => $index,
 );

if(count($array) < 20) {
   // redirect
} else {
  // do nothing
}

$index++;
}
```

**In my case, i want to redirect member to another page if there are not 20 items.**
But when i check ['20'] and setup else, other 1 to 19 are still there, and redirect are going also if member have ['20'] exist.

How i can make it happend, if member have 20 items to dont redirect, and if there is less then 20 items to redirect?

Thanks !

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. It looks like your whole code could be reduced to something like `$index = count($partialStructure); $array = array($index => $index);`

Comment: You dont show any code that is making a decision on when to do what. Add the code you have now to make that decision and the question may become more clear to us all

Comment: OR you can add direct check on `$partialStructure` variable like `count($partialStructure) < 20`

Comment: The problem is getting more complicated. In my foreach i have another comment calling 
$tmp = $this->getFieldValueString($field, $value, $subject, $map, $partialStructure);

This when i do count($tmp) its show 1, but there are 20 items to my member. Now, i dont know, but the with index as array , i can count that $tmp have 20 items. Problem is that foreach goes 1 to 19, if member have 20 or less, all are redirected, instead only one who have less then 20 ...

Comment: I make small improvment in my code to understand what i am doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the length of the array rather than computing the length through iterating through it.

```
if(count($array)) < 20) {
  //redirect
}else{
  //do whatever you need to do
}
```

[count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the php function count() to get the number of elements in your array ;)
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 0):

I fix my code like this:

```
$counter = 0;
$tmp= array();
foreach( $partialStructure as $map ) {

 // i am getting specific number of $tmp for specific subject ( member )
 $tmp[] = $this->getFieldValueString($field, $value, $subject, $map, $partialStructure);

if($tmp['20'])
$counter++;


}
// out of foreach element, i setup this
if($counter == 0) {
   header("Location: /members/edit/profile?redirect=1");     
}
```

$counter will give you 1, if tmp['20'] is there, else, you can do the redirect...